# Ubuntu 12.10 not properply working on Asus u46E after Update

Tags: wireless, kernel, 12.10, internet

I recently installed the latest Ubuntu update on my laptop and since then, the alignment on the browser is messed up, the mouse is not working, and I can't connect to the internet.  Before it was working perfectly.

Any ideas on what to do?  Thanks for any feedback

FYI: I am right now using windows since I have both Linux and windows on my laptop.  Also, when booting I do have the option to boot previous Ubuntu versions, when I boot the previous Ubuntu version on my laptop, everything works accept except the internet.  (the mouse works, alignment is proper)

Comment: Is your Internet connection (for laptop) Ethernet or WiFi?

Comment: I am using wi fi